# how create companion object variable from argument of their parent class

Tags: android, kotlin

I was developing an app where I need to keep in memory some object with a reference string, so I think to use a singleton like companion object.

My problem comes because I get an error when I try to pass the object an the reference string.

Here is my code:

```
class PulseSender(gpioName: String) {
    internal val logger = getLogger("PIN/PAD", "PAX-Device")
    private val peripheralManager = PeripheralManager.getInstance() 
    private val pinGPIO: Gpio = peripheralManager.openGpio(gpioName)

    companion object{
        val gpio : Map<String, Gpio> = mapOf(gpioName, pinGPIO) //Both argument rise an error
    }
    val staticGpio get() = gpio

...
}
```

Do you kow some way to correctly pass those arguments correctly (gpioName is a String Gpio is an object), or I should change my aproach?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for a companion object to refer to anything within the class it's defined in, because it's static. What if you have multiple `PulseSender` instances, which should the companion object refer to then? It feels to me like you want it to be a map containing the `Gpio` of all `PulseSender` instances. In that case you maybe want this:

```
class PulseSender(gpioName: String) {
    internal val logger = getLogger("PIN/PAD", "PAX-Device")
    private val peripheralManager = PeripheralManager.getInstance() 
    private val pinGPIO: Gpio = peripheralManager.openGpio(gpioName)

    init {
        gpio[gpioName] = pinGPIO
    }
    companion object{
        val gpio : MutableMap<String, Gpio> = mutableMapOf()
    }
...
}
```

Also having that `staticGpio` getter doesn't make much sense. Why even have that if you can access `gpio` directly (from anywhere).

I feel like you might not fully understand what a companion object actually is. They are by definition static and accessible from anywhere